# Vaadin 14 Time Picker - align centered

Tags: java, css, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin-themes

with Vaadin 14(.1.19) comes this Time Picker component: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-time-picker/java-examples

This is how it looks like (when it's read-only):

[image: Vaadin Time Picker component normal]

How can I get this Time Picker to show the time centered like this (this is a screenshot of a manual manipulation in the browser (setting text-align:center directly at the embedded input field), not a programmed solution)?

[image: Vaadin Time Picker component with centered text]

I tried to set the text-align property in the Java code without effect:

```
TimePicker timepicker = new TimePicker();
timepicker.getElement().getStyle().set("text-align", "center");
```

And I searched for a theme variant. But that seems to exist for TextFields and derived fields only:

```
EmailField emailFeld = new EmailField();
emailFeld.addThemeVariants(TextFieldVariant.LUMO_ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change the CSS within the shadow DOM of `TimePicker`'s `TextField` value part, we use theme attribute as additional selector in order to not to theme all the text fields:

```
[part="value"] {
    :host([theme~="center"]) text-align: center;
}
```

Include the CSS via `@CssImport` annotation, theming the text field and set the theme attribute to the date picker. The theme attribute is propagated to the text field used in the date picker:

```java
@CssImport(value = "./styles/my-time-picker-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-time-picker-text-field")
public class YourViewOrLayout extends Composite<Div> {
   ...
   timePicker.getElement().setAttribute("theme", "center");
}
```

I explained it in bit more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553658/1063673).

Comment: Hi Steffen and hi Tatu, thank you both!
It works with two modifications:

First I exchanged the value of "themeFor":
@CssImport(value = "./styles/time-picker-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-time-picker-text-field").
I also tried "vaadin-text-field" and "vaadin-time-picker". But for "vaadin-time-picker" the browser placed the style property in a shadow root too high.

And second I removed "host([theme~="center"])".
I also tried to move it outside the braces but that had no (visible) influence at all. Yes, this way all TimePickers are centered. This is OK for my case.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it should be "vaadin-time-picker-text-field". Regarding the "theme", I am not even sure whether this is valid CSS. Maybe @Tatu (edited) could point that out? I guess `:host([theme~="center"])[part="value"] { text-align: center; }` should work.

Comment: No, this does not work. The vaadin-time-picker element has attribut theme = "center". In the shadow root of vaadin-time-picker element there is a vaadin-combo-box-light element. In that there is a vaadin-time-picker-text-field element. In its shadow root there is a style element with ":host([theme~="center"])[part="value"] { text-align: center; }" and also the slot element with the input in it. So the CSS selector would have to be ":host[...] :host[...]" or something like that - I don't know. But nevertheless your answer helped me. :-)